# Removing last element of a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I've been working on a project in Python, coding a little game that's basically the number version of mastermind. Anyway, I came across a bug in my program and I'm curious as to why this is:

I had a list, and when removing the last element of the list, the order of the remaining elements changed. For example:

```
myList = [4, 4, 5, 4]

myList.remove(myList[3])
```

The contents of the list were now `[4, 5, 4]` instead of `[4, 4, 5]`. This did not happen with most other combinations of numbers which is why I am confused. Also, if I instead use:

```
myList = myList[:-1]
```

This works and the contents are in the correct order... Does anyone know why removing the last element the first way didn't work in this case?

Comment: `remove` removes the _first matching value_, in this case `4` (`myList[3]`). There has to be a good duplicate for this.

Comment: the remove function removed the first element with the value you entered, in this case you passed the value 4 (from index 3) and it removed the element at index 1 which happened to have the same value

Comment: Your confusion has been answered. I'd just like to point out that you might want to look at the `pop` method on lists. It does exactly what you want it to - remove the last element of the list.

Answer (score 4):

```
myList.remove(myList[3])
```

is the same as doing

```
myList.remove(4)
```

and remove always removes the first instance. You should try doing:

```
del a[-1]
```

or as mentioned by @Megalng

```
a.pop()
```

which also returns the removed element

Answer (score -3):

```
del myList[-1]
```

got to love the python